# Dynamically creating triangle with max-width/fit inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, geometry

I have a web page that accepts three inputs.
I am dynamically creating a triangle from these three inputs (by setting border-widths).
I want the triangle to fit inside the div on the page. For example, if the inputs were 500, 500, 300 I want to reduce these to fit inside the div on the page while retaining the aspect ratio of the inputs.

HTML:

```
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#triangle {  
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#triangle").css({
  "border-left": length1 + "px solid transparent",
  "border-right": length2 + "px solid transparent",
  "border-bottom": length3 + "px solid #2383ea"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it.

Start with the following **HTML**, two nested block elements:

```
<div id="triangle"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

and some basic **CSS**:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#triangle {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#triangle .inner {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

and now use the following jQuery/JavaScript:

```js
var length1 = 1500;
var length2 = 1500;
var length3 = 1500;

var maxWidth = parseInt($("#triangle").css("max-width"));

var baseWidth = Math.min($("#triangle").width(),maxWidth);
var scale = baseWidth/(length1+length2);

$("#triangle .inner").css({
  "border-left": length1*scale + "px solid red",
  "border-right": length2*scale + "px solid green",
  "border-bottom": length3*scale+ "px solid #2383ea"
});
```

You can see a demo at:  http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/WVcvj/

### Programming Notes

You will enter the `length1`, `length2` and `length3` from a form or something.

By default, `#triangle` will take on the width of the parent container, so use that width if it is smaller than the maximum width (you can get the value using the `.css` function). The `parseInt()` function will strip out the `px` label that comes with the value.

The base of the triangle has a width of `length1+length2`, so calculate the ratio of the available width to the specified width.

You then normalize the three border widths and you are done!

Comment: I'm pretty late on the reply. But thank you for your help. I notice though that there's a bug (of sorts). If you input 200, 200, 200 the expected result is an equilateral triangle. Sure the borders are each 200px, but that is the distance from the edge. How can you build it so it actually displays an equilateral triangle? It's tough.